# Problem images firefox

Tags: html, image, firefox

I have a big problem with my web site ([you can see here](http://morwen-world.com)), several user can't see images with firefox. I use too firefox but I don't have this problem.

These users use firefox 3.5.2 with windows XP or VISTA. I have no idea to find the problem.
Have you any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The images load fine for me, but the text seems all corrupted - I can't make head nor tail of it :-)

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Neither+head+nor+tail

Comment: +1 Pax..that's the first link i have even seen on SO for explaining a phrase :D

Comment: Haha very funny but I'm not american or english man so I don't understand your sentence. So perhaps you can rewrite it with other words.

Comment: Sorry, @Kiva, I shouldn't use humor in an international setting (my wife says I shouldn't use it at all). It was a joke because all the text was in French and the only phrase I remember from my high school French is "Je voudrais un kilo de pomme de terre sil vous plait" which is not too useful as you can imagine (and may be horribly misspelled as well).

Comment: No problem pax, and the site is a french web site like you see ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the user has accidentally blocked images from your domain.

In Firefox:

**Tools** > **Options** > **Content** tab > **Load images automatically** should be checked > click **Exceptions...** make sure the *Site* list does not include `mowen-world.com`. If it is there, highlight it and click **Remove Site**.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues a few weeks ago. The reason was that the JPG images were somehow corrupted. Some browsers/OS combinations showed them without problems, but on others they didn't show.

I fixed it by opening every JPG image and saving them again in a good image editor (like Photoshop or Fireworks)

Comment: Ho my god, bad news, I'll try this but it's boring ^^

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get a problem like this, I start from basics... like "is the HTML valid".

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmorwen-world.com%2F

There are some issues listed here that could cause odd behaviour.

When I look at the site, I can see all the images fine and the website looks reasonably well laid out (Firefox 3.0.14 Windows XP AND Internet Explorer 8 Windows XP).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an issue using Firefox 3.5.3 on Windows Vista, just FYI.

Personally whenever I have issues with assets not loading or markup/CSS behaving weirdly, my first stop is [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843). The Net panel shows the requests for any images and their respective responses. Certainly a good place to start looking.

Comment: I use firebug but I haven't the problem, so I can't use it to solve the problem.